# Необходимость указания времени жизни в Rust когда компилятор может вывести время жизни сам

Tags: rust, время-жизни

Почему этот код вызывает ошибку:

```
const MSG: &str = "Hello";

fn one_of(_first: &str, _second: &str) -> &str {
    MSG
}
```

Задал это вопрос своему железному другу (gpt-4-1106-preview) и он ответил:

> Код вызывает ошибку, потому что Rust не может гарантировать, что
> строка, на которую ссылается `MSG`, будет жить достаточно долго, чтобы
> безопасно использовать возвращаемую ссылку из функции `one_of`

Ну, ладно, допустим, тогда почему эта функция НЕ вызывает ошибку:

```
const MSG: &str = "Hello";

fn one(_first: &str) -> &str {
    MSG
}
```

Мой друг ответил:

> Когда функция `one` объявлена без явного указания времени жизни для
> возвращаемой ссылки, компилятор использует вывод времени жизни и
> видит, что возвращаемое значение `MSG` имеет статическое время жизни.
> В результате компилятор считает, что функция возвращает ссылку со
> статическим временем жизни, и этот вывод совместим с временем жизни
> входного параметра (который в данном случае игнорируется, так как не
> используется для определения времени жизни возвращаемого значения).

на мое резонное возражение:

> но ведь и вслучае one_of компилятор может автоматически присвоить функции
> статическое время жизни, как и в случае one, почему все, что ты сказал
> по поводу one недействительно в случае с функцией one_of?

Мой друг окончательно сломался, начал извиняться "за путаницу", и заявил, что обе функции не должны вызывать ошибку (хотя, это не так).

Требуется помощь биологических нейросетей, то есть вас, уважаемые кожаные и костистые друзья! Объясните сабж

Comment: Не умеет gpt находить ошибки в коде, бесполезно квоту на него тратить. Пишет обычно такую чушь, что уши в трубочку сворачиваются. Хорошая иллюстрация этого.

Comment: Во втором случае срабатывает [второе правило lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.ru/stable/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html): если на входе одна ссылка, то на выходе ссылка получит такое же время жизни. В первом же случае на входе ссылок две, и компилятор не знает чьё время жизни выбрать - и заставляет выбирать вас. При этом тело функции не имеет никакого значения - времена жизни это часть сигнатуры функции, и то, что вы возвращаете статический MSG, ни на что не влияет

Comment: @andreymal Отлично! До этой книжки я еще не дошел, читаю https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/title-page.html только, а там про время жизни довольно мутно написано. Спасибо за наводку!

Comment: @Глеб новая версия теста Тьюринга: если ChatGPT начнёт понимать принципы работы владения, заимствования и времён жизни в Rust, то будет пора начинать беспокоиться за будущее человечества 

Comment: @andreymal Оказывается есть там подраздел, но я еще до него не дошел, когда у меня возник этот вопрос, по поводу которого у меня возникло беспокойство и я не мог двигаться дальше, пока на него для себя не отвечу. Так я сам стал жертвой своего собственного перфекционизма как формы неврастении ;D Оказывается, в старых версиях языка, аннотацию времени жизни надо было указывать и в случае таких как `one`! (да и Искусственному Идиоту надо меньше доверять)

Comment: А да, [вот в книге они есть](https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8) (перевели по-другому, поэтому я сам не сразу заметил)

Comment: @andreymal комментарии достойны быть ответом ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда функция возвращает ссылку, компилятор должен знать её время жизни. Под "знать" понимается "определить время жизни ссылки по сигнатуре функции" без исследования тела функции. Во имя сохранения труда программистов в Rust придумали [правила неявного выведения времени жизни](https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8) возвращаемого значения.

В данном случае функция получает на вход две разных ссылки, компилятор не решается определить, к времени жизни какой из них нужно привязать время жизни возвращаемой ссылки. Требуется подсказать ему, например так:

```
fn one_of<'a>(_first: &'a str, _second: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    MSG
}
```

Comment: как вариант, более подходящий к изначальному коду, можно объявить функцию: fn one_of(_first: &str, _second: &str) -> &'static str